# My Joomla! site loads too slowly

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

My Joomla! site loads very slowly and sometimes return an error which is:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in `D:\Hosting\6926666\html\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php` on line 11
Note that the `D:\Hosting\6926666\html\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php` on line 11 
alayws changes  (not the same path).

**Hint**: In local my site working very good, the problem happened when the site and the database are on the server, or the database is only on the server.
My site is Joomla! 1.6 and my host server is godaddy.com

Comment: Godaddy is TERRIBLE for joomla sites.  I used them for years - at first they were okay when they were just starting out; but over the years their servers are over-shared, over-loaded piles of poop that really don't do well with Joomla sites at all.  I always (ALWAYS) recommend people get FAR away from godaddy for reasons like this.  Sorry, but that's your problem - has nothing to do with Joomla or your coding, but rather with a poor server host.

Comment: Not sure how you can *guarantee* that it has *nothing* to do with joomla, or the asker's coding. If godaddy were absolutely useless for all sites, they wouldn't be in business. So there must be *something* about this specific setup that is contributing to the 'problem'. Where the 'fault' lies is another issue.

Comment: While it is probably a Godaddy issues, you are probably on a loaded server, you really should confirm it one way or another. You should also upgrade from 1.6, that has been obsolete for a year. Use the built in upgrade system.

Answer (score 3):

I changed to another template and the website sped up considerably.  I then did some investigating and found the index.php of the template has been HACKED and there was EVAL() and BASE 64() code in there!  As soon as I put in a "clean" version of the PHP, the website was back to normal!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jav_Rock : godaddy is not "compatible" with Joomla.

So, to solve your problem, you should find another hosting provider!

Answer (score 0):

for:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

first create a `php.ini` file and place the code only 'max_execution_time=120' means execution time is 120 Sec. or 2 Minute. or modify according to you..

and put that file into you joomla administrator folder.
Or you can directly edit the `php.ini` if you have access on it.

also enable cache for the required modules.

Comment: That's putting a bandaid on an amputation. The pages shouldn't be taking 30 seconds to load in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any third-party extensions? If so, how many? The more you use, the more likely it is that one of them has introduced an 'issue'.

I'd like to suggest that you review the code and database structure associated with each extension to determine where there might be a problem. I'm currently doing this with a fairly simple site that is using a LOT of extensions (so many that it breaks the admin UI). Some of them are terribly written - e.g. making many database lookups when 1 is required, writing to the database with every single request, storing several values in a single column, etc.

However, you say you're a 'beginner', so I think your best bet is either:

- Get someone who is *not* a beginner to do the above review for you
- Experiment by enabling/disabling each extension in turn to determine which are problematic. That's not very scientific, but might get you somewhere.

If you can, try enabling debug (you can do that via the Global Configuration). This will show you - amongst other things - how many database queries are required to generate your page. I can't give you an absolute figure for what is 'good' or not, suffice it to say that fewer is better! So, for example, if you identify a low-priority extension whose removal saves you 25% of the total, you might well decide to disable that module - and, possibly, look for an alternative. As a guide, the site I'm working on originally made 500-600 queries for the home page. In my opinion that is far, FAR too many.